# gradle download artifact version as given

Tags: java, gradle

In my gradle project, there is dependency to version *19.6.0-rel.1* of a library. The jar is actually available in project's maven repository, but the version details are missing in *maven-metadata.xml*. As I understood, gradle interprets the version mentioned above as as a snapshot version or something and hence checks the maven-metadata.xml.

How can I force gradle to download that exact version and to ignore maven-metadata.xml?

(Note that I cannot change the version of the library as its 3rd party.)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went ahead with a higher version of the library.

But I later found how to specify exact dependency version with Gradle here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/single_versions.html.

```
implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api") {
    version {
       strictly '1.7.15'
    }
}
```